# nested for loop in a function array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am working on a c++ homework assignment for arrays and functions, and this is what I have so far and am not even sure if I am on the right path or not. These are the exact instructions..

*Write a program to ask the user to enter a total of N numbers which you will store in main local array of Define N as a constant int and initialize it to 6. You will write the following functions:
FillArray( ) – accepts two inputs: (1) the array. (2) the array size. Returns nothing.
•   Prompts the user to enter N elements (N =  the array size and the variables you pass should have been defined as a constant int in main( )
•   Use a for loop to enter and store the value of each element in the array*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
cout << "Enter 6 numbers for the array:" << endl; 

FillArray();

return 0;

}

void FillArray(){

int n;
int array[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,};
void fillarray(const int n[], int size);


for (; n > 6; n++) 
    cin >> array[n];
cout << "Thank you\n";


}
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.. thank you!

Comment: Well for one thing, you certainly didn't obey the directive to use a constant `N` for the number of values to read. You just wrote 6 everywhere.

Comment: You failed to define your array and the constant in the int main, you also failed to create a function that can take two arguments

Comment: Does this even compile? You have a nested function declaration inside your `FillArray` function. Also you never initialize `n` and your condition in the `for` loop is wrong

Comment: @UnholySheep The only thing I can see here that prevents compilation here is that `FillArray` is undeclared when it's used in `main`. You're allowed to declare functions locally. It's likely not what OP meant to do though.

Answer (score 1):

> Write a program to ask the user to enter a total of N numbers which
>   you will store in **main local array** of **Define N as a constant int and
>   initialize it to 6**

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 6;
    int a[N];

    //...
```

> You will write the following functions: FillArray( ) – **accepts two
>   inputs: (1) the array. (2) the array size**.

```
//...
FillArray( a, N );

//...

void FillArray( int a[], int n )
{
    cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers for the array: "; 

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}
```

And the name of the function used in the program shall be declared before its using

```
void FillArray( int a[], int n );

int main()
{
    //...
```

Comment: It looks like @Vlad gets an A for the assignment...too bad he's not enrolled int he course!  Or is he?

Comment: Nah. Vlad gets a F because the instructor finds the submitted solution is a copy of one online... written by Vlad. This causes the instructor to go insane and is carried away screaming about how much easier teaching math would be if Pi was 3. A shame, really.